# Styling Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am working on a Wordpress site using the theme 'Enfold' and have customized the built in 'Portfolio' option of the theme to be a House & Land Package real estate like [page](http://northharbour-newbrand.portfolio.com.au/house-land-packages/)

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to make it easy for people who aren't developers to add new packages including the information such as price and how many bed/bath/car spaces it has.

The PHP code section where the ACF is grabbed from is marked up as:

```
$output .= get_post_meta( $entry->ID, "package_price", true );
$output .= !empty($title) || !empty($excerpt) ? "</div>" : '';
$output .= get_post_meta( $entry->ID, "bed", true );
$output .= get_post_meta( $entry->ID, "bath", true );
$output .= get_post_meta( $entry->ID, "car", true );
```

I'd like to be able to style it using CSS but just cannot work out how to with this particular code. Can anyone help?

Comment: For things like this after implementing this code you go to your live site and inspect(using developer tools) on those elements(html  tags) the find out their markup id and classes they carry. Then you can target it anyhow you want from the style sheet(i think to style admin area for wordpress as to be in the functions.php)

Comment: I have used the inspect element tool and there is no element markup for these areas which has me puzzled.